# Reserve sequence range in DB2

Tags: database, oracle, db2, sequence, database-migration

We are moving application from Oracle to DB2. It is a batch job. There is a sequencing logic that assigns ids to entries before processing:

1. Reserve range of sequences

   select MY_SEQUENCE.nextval; // range_start;

   alter sequence MY_SEQUENCE increment by RANGE_SIZE;

   select MY_SEQUENCE.nextval;

   alter sequence MY_SEQUENCE increment by 1;

   select MY_SEQUENCE.nextval; // range_end;
2. Assign ids from within a range via in-memory incremented value:

   for id = range_start:range_end do

This worked fine in Oracle, but gave unexpected results in DB2.

In Oracle:

```
DROP SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE;
CREATE SEQUENCE  MY_SEQUENCE MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 50000 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 1;
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 2;
ALTER SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE INCREMENT BY 100000;
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 100002;
ALTER SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE INCREMENT BY 1;
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 100003;
```

In DB2:

```
DROP SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE;
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE AS DECIMAL(27 , 0)  START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 NO CYCLE CACHE 50000 NO ORDER;

SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 1;
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 2;
ALTER SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE INCREMENT BY 100000;
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 150000;
ALTER SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE INCREMENT BY 1;
SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; // 5000050001;
```

I think 150000 may be explained by CACHE size. However I have no idea yet about 5000050001 value. Any help here is highly appreciated.

Notes:

- Im aware of alter statements being non-transactional. However the process have exclusive access to the DB the time it is launched and runs non-distributed and single-threaded.
- DB2 runs in ORA compatibility mode
- The same issue in DB2 appears if DB2 sequence next val is used: VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE;
- Same issue for ordered sequences

Comment: I think the fact that this is part of your process means that the process is flawed in the first place.  `ALTER` should be _rare_, usually one-off statements.  What the heck are you doing jumping ranges like that in the first place?  Autogen id values aren't supposed to matter (usually).  This suggests that you have some sort of multi-part key, which violates good normalization practices.  If you really need to do something like this, I'd use 2 sequences - one that jumps by `100000` each time, and one that jumps by `1` (that, or see if `ROW_NUMBER()` gives reasonable results).

Comment: however I will need 'alter' to sync-up sequences after my process finishes, right?

Comment: Yeah, you'd still have to reset the sequences for the next batch job (which I'd probably recommend doing at the next start).  But I still think the fact that you're doing this means you have a poorly designed or implemented process.  If this is for tracking purposes, just use a single autogen id.  Presumably each larger jump signals what should be part of a parent table, and the small ones are part of a child table...

Comment: This id is not for tracking. It does some pre-processing and linking the data. However I agree that this doesn't look like good impl. Probably some sequencing service would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering sequence to NO CACHE fixed the issue.

Comment: If smb knows the better answer that doesn't require altering to NO CACHE, I will accept that.

Comment: There is no other answer -- the first access to the sequence caches as many values as specified by the `CACHE` clause, and since you set the increment value to 100000 the sequence moves forward by 50000 times 100000.